# fullpagejs auto fit to content in mobile with responsiveWidth

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

In mobile (at least IOS) sometimes fits to the section when you are touching the screen. Every section has `fp-auto-height-responsive` and this code:

```
responsiveWidth: 900,
css3: true,
normalScrollElements: '#generate-slideout-menu, body.slide-opened #site-navigation',
easingcss3: "ease",
```

The objective is, jump scroll in desktop and normal scrolling in mobile.

Ok i recently discover it happens because i have

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function (event) {
      fullpage_api.reBuild();
    });
```

I use this in desktop to be smooth the resize windows, but it conflicts in mobile. Any solution?

Comment: Why are you calling `reBuild` on resize? There's no need for that, fullpgae.js does it for you.

Comment: Because It looks like resize smoother

Comment: What it looks its laggy and performing so bad, as it will call the rebuild method hundreds of time while resizing. But hey, if you like it, who am I to tell you not to ;D